# Finding Big-O of the following function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I have the following question that I need to give the Big Oh estimate for:

$$(n^n +n2^n+5^n)(n!+2^n).$$

I tried to expand this:

$$n^nn! + n^n2^n + n2^nn! + n2^{2n} + 5^nn! + 5^n2^n$$

Would the Big Oh then be $O(n^nn!)$?

Comment: If $n\geq 5$ then $$
n2^n  = 2n2^{n - 1}  \le 2nn^{n - 1}  = 2n^n ,\quad 5^n  \le n^n ,\quad 2^n  \le n!.
$$ This gives you $O(n^nn!)$. Clearly your expression is $>n^n n!$ so this is a realistic big-$O$ estimate.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the" big-O estimate. Anything that stays bigger than a constant times the given expression is a big-O estimate. You might, for example, want to get rid of the factorial, using $n!=O(n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n})$.

Answer (score 1):

For any function $f(n)$ where $$(n^n +n2^n+5^n)(n!+2^n) < Cf(n)$$ for all $n$, where $C>0$ is a constant, you can say your function is $O(f(n))$.

In this case, yes your function is $O(n^n n!)$. As another commenter pointed out, you can estimate $n!$ by $\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{n}$, up to a constant, so your function is $O\left(\frac{n^{2n+{1\over 2}}}{e^n}\right)$.

Maybe the neatest way to write this is
$$O\left(\left(\frac{n^2}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{n}\right).$$